# Windows 8, pendrive - directory changed name to some strange one and removed all files

Tags: windows, windows-8, usb, usb-flash-drive

I am using windows 8 and I have weird problem with directory on my pendrive.

I had USB pendrive connected to my laptop and I did something in one of directories inside. Structure of this directory included another directories and simple word files.

I closed laptop and move pendrive to other computer. When I opened data from pendrive, my directory had changed name to some strange signs (circles, squares, etc.) and it is blank (like hidden directory). Also it looks like all directories inside are removed (size is 0 B). I tried to use some program to recovery them, but unlucky - they do not see any files there.

Is it any possibility to recover all files? What could happend here? I do not have any infections, but it looks very strange that only one directory is destroyed (another ones are ok).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some memory chip in that USB got wrecked and the pendrive couldn't relocate the data. I think the other directories are OK only by luck, being placed in other memory chips.
If a recovery data program like Recuva or running an old chkdsk can't recover anything, I'm afraid that you should replace that pendrive as soon as possible.